# How do I resolve templated circular dependencies with a has-a relationship?

Tags: c++

I have a class named `EntityManager` that owns `Entity` in a `vector`. The issue is, `Entity` uses a reference to `EntityManager` in a templated function. Here is code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
//EntityManager.h
#include "Entity.h"
class EntityManager{
    std::vector<Entity> ents;
public:
    template<class T>
    void someFunc(const Entity & e){
        ...
    }
};

//Entity.h
#include "EntityManager.h"
class Entity{
    EntityManager * mgr;
public:
    template<class T>
    void someOtherFunc(){
        mgr->someFunc<T>(*this);
    }
}
```

Note, I have tried to move the function out of the declaration like so:

```
//Entity.h
class EntityManager;

class Entity{
    EntityManager & mgr;
public:
    template<class T>
    void someOtherFunc();
}

#include "EntityManager.h"
template<class T>
void Entity::someOtherFunc(){
    mgr->someFunc<T>(*this);
}
```

How do I resolve this dependency? Note, I cannot use C++11, just in case the solution is hidden there.

Comment: There's always changing the mgr to being a pointer to a Entity Manager (this may not be the most elegant solution though).

Comment: A pointer doesn't work either I'm afraid. I used one originally, just typed up the question with a reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your dependencies are as follows:

- `EntityManager` contains a `vector` of `Entity`s. The class definition of `EntityManager` requires the class definition of `Entity` in order to be well-defined.
- `Entity` contains a reference to an `EntityManager`. Its class definition requires the type declaration *only* of `EntityManager` in order to be well-defined.
- The implementation of `EntityManager::someFunc<T>` requires the class definitions of both `EntityManager` and `Entity`.
- The implementation of `Entity::someOtherFunc<T>` also requires the class definitions of both `EntityManager` and `Entity`.

So, the solution would be:

- to include the class definition of `Entity` before `EntityManager`
- to forward-declare `EntityManager` before the class definition of `Entity`
- *not* to include the class definition of `EntityManager` before the class definition of `Entity`
- but to remember to include the class definition of `EntityManager` before the implementation of `Entity::someOtherFunc<T>`, and the class definition of `Entity` before the implementation of `EntityManager::someFunc<T>`

This should break the cycle. The key insight is that although you can usually get away with writing member function templates inline, in this case you must split them from the class definition. If you express the dependencies declaratively and use the appropriate `#include` guards, the definitions will be included in the correct order automatically.

For example,

**EntityManager.h**

The class definition of `EntityManager` requires the class definition of `Entity`. The header needs to include the implementation of `EntityManager`'s templated member functions.

```
#ifndef ENTITYMANAGER_H
#define ENTITYMANAGER_H
#include "Entity.h"

class EntityManager {
  std::vector<Entity> ents;
public:
  template <typename T>
  inline void someFunc(const Entity &e);
};

#include "EntityManager.cpp.tmpl"

#endif
```

**EntityManager.cpp.tmpl**

The implementation of `EntityManager` requires the class definition of `Entity`.

```
#include "Entity.h"

template <typename T>
void EntityManager::someFunc(const Entity &e) {
  // do things with this, e, and T
}
```

**Entity.h**

The class definition of `Entity` only requires the declaration of the `EntityManager` type. The header needs to include the implementation of `Entity`'s templated member functions.

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H
class EntityManager;

class Entity {
  EntityManager &mgr;
public:
  template <typename T>
  inline void someOtherFunc();
};

#include "Entity.cpp.tmpl"

#endif
```

**Entity.cpp.tmpl**

The implementation of `Entity` requires the class definition of `EntityManager`.

```
#include "EntityManager.h"

template <typename T>
void Entity::someOtherFunc() {
  mgr.someFunc<T>(*this);
}
```

Comment: Note that Entity has to have `someOtherFunc` defined in the header and so we need to include `EntityManager.h` to define it correctly. I can't do that since if I do, the header guard kicks in and we don't have a definition of the class `EntityManager`

Comment: Correct, you will be unable to reference any specific members of `mgr` inside the class definition, because that would require the full class definition of `EntityManager`, which already requires the full definition of `Entity`. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The definition of a templated function must be accessible by whoever calls it. If I put it inside the .cpp files, I have to have full template specialization for all of my `someOtherFunc` and `someFunc` calls.

Comment: Just tried this, accepting the answer before doing so. It still doesn't work, with the same problem as before. `Entity.cpp.tmpl` using the incomplete type of `EntityManager`.

Comment: Hmm, I was able to get it to compile for me. Can you post your complete code?